# Displaying an attribute in a tab

Tags: php, magento

I have been trying to display a product attribute that i created called “PDF” in a tab. I tried to re-use the code that had been used to get the product description but change it to reference my new Attribute, well so i thought.

This is the code i used:

The attribute code is: pdf 
Admin title is: PDF

```
<?php $_pdf = $this->getProduct()->getPDF(); ?>
<?php if ($_pdf): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('PDF') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_pdf, 'pdf') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I maybe no where near where i have to be but i am new to magento and new to PHP as well.

I dont want to have to use any extensions if possible.

If you can fix this for me you will be a god! thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$this->getProduct()->getPDF()` when you should be using `$this->getProduct()->getPdf()`. Magento camel cases attribute names for its magic methods.

You could also use `$this->getProduct()->getData('pdf')`.

Comment: You sir are a legend! thank you so much i have been having this problem for so long and now it works!!!!